# ASP.NET MVC Registration With Captcha

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, captcha

I would like to allow my users to register from homepage by entering name, surname, email and password information. After submitting the form, I want to redirect my users to a security check page for a capthca validation. User will be saved to the database after this captcha validation. The scenario is similar to Facebook's homepage registration feature.

My problem is, after collecting name, surname, email and password information how can I send them to the captcha validation page in a secure manner (not sending them with querystring, because password will be plain there). TempData and Session usage will not be followed in this project.

Thank you!

Comment: why not put the captcha on the same page and catch it before any submission happens?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to just put the captcha on the same page?

Comment: Because I dont have that much space on the homepage, and captcha image is not in harmony with my homepage design

Comment: How are you going to maintain the authentication state of your users without storing some session data? You need maintain some state, I.e. FilledInCaptcha, IsAuthenticated, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use Recaptcha for .NET (http://recaptchanet.codeplex.com) to use a robust and secure captcha solution for your MVC .NET project.

When you submit the form, create a cookie and encrypt its values with the user's session ID as its key and have its expiration time to be something like 5 minutes. Read the cookie from the captcha page. I am assuming that you don't want to store the values on the server and query string is obviously not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using **MVCRecaptcha** (https://mvcrecaptcha.codeplex.com/). Please note - specifically MVCRecaptcha and not some of the other closely related implementations.

Download the package from Nuget, however, make SURE that you don't download the other Recaptcha packages that are available - you should specifically download MVC recaptcha.

Then follow the rest of the instructions on the MVC recaptcha codeplex site to get up and running.